# Where can I access playlists that I saved but are not my own creation

Tags: youtube, youtube-playlist

I have a habit of making large todo lists, admittedly too large, loads of stuff just gets deleted. YouTube could be very good for this since there are a lot of pre-existing playlists that fit my needs. Making a playlist of my own just seems too much of a hassle when perfectly good playlists are already out there.

My question is: After I save them, where do they go? They are definitely not in my playlists "directory", and I see no "saved playlists" anywhere.

I admit: I know they already appear on the drop down sidebar thingy, but that's such a horrible implementation that it hurts my brain. There simply has to be something else also!

**EDIT** I can't see the created playlists button:

The created playlists thing is just plain text.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

UPDATE: This has been fixed for my channels and I don't see this bug anymore.

This feature is broken on some channels. If, after saving a playlist, you don't see 'Saved playlists' section when you go to playlists, then your channel is affected and you can't see them.

I have several YouTube channels and this bug affects some of them but not all.

Comment: Can you confirm if the following works on one of your affected channels.
Remove `viewas=subscriber` (if present) and add `?view=52` at the end of the url on the playlists page, so as to directly bring up the "Saved Playlists" view.
For example, if your channels playlist page url is `youtube.com/channel/<CHANNEL_ID>/playlists` it becomes `youtube.com/channel/<CHANNEL_ID>/playlists?view=52`

Comment: @AdityaSriram This bug has been fixed for my channels, so I don't have any affected channels anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, they do go to the playlists directory. Perhaps yours is set to "Created playlists" instead of "All playlists"?

I'm using Chrome on a Windows PC and, when you posted your screenshot, at first I thought you were not. After some clicking around, though, I noticed that the layout of that screen can change depending on where you're coming from. So, by clicking on "My Channel" first and **then** on "Playlists", I finally got a screen with the same layout as yours ("View as" field, "Home" tab etc). The "All playlists / Created playlists / Saved playlists" dropdown list is still there, though: it only gets replaced by the "Created playlists" label (like in your screenshot) if I delete all my saved playlists. I hate to ask you this, but are you positive that the account you're logged in is the same account where you saved the playlists?

[image]

Comment: I can't see that drop-down.

Comment: To expand my comment: I have no such button at all. It just writes: Created playlists in plain text.

Comment: Looking at the screenshot you've added, I noticed that the top of the screen is slightly different from what I see here. For example, I don't have a "View as" field or a "Home" tab. It seems that we both made a rookie mistake in that we didn't tell which OS / browser we're using. :-) I'm using Chrome on a Windows PC. What about you?

Comment: Also using chrome. I wish I knew what was going on ...

Comment: Some channels are bugged and don't show 'Saved playlists' at all.

Comment: @Kalec Pardon the years-late reply, but see [my answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/115845/180552). In short, one must delete the "?view_as=subscriber" from the URL, to get the dropdown. Alternatively, one can open the top-right ☰ menu and click on the word "LIBRARY" (that looks like a section heading, but is actually linked to a Playlists page that simultaneously shows both your own playlists and others' playlists you've "+"ed).

Comment: @MarkusLaire see my response to Kalec, above.

Answer (score 2):

On a browser, if you expand the hamburger menu at the top right, then look under 'Library' you will see the saved playlist there. You will only see the playlist there once the page has been refreshed.

I am not sure if this is the only place.

Answer (score 1):

All of the playlists which you have saved and are not owned by you are saved into your [YouTube Library](https://www.youtube.com/feed/library) under 'Playlists'. The YouTube Library contains the categorized list of History, Watch Later, Playlists, and Liked Videos.

Answer (score 0):

2018 answer (It's possible some things have shifted around a bit since this question was first asked.)

**TL:DR version:**

Either

1. Go to the URL https://www.youtube.com/user and click "Saved playlists"
   or
2. Open the the top-left hamburger ("☰") menu button, and then click on the word "LIBRARY"

---

**Further explanation:**

Some understandable confusion appears to be arising because some people are going to their top-right user menu and clicking on either their username or "My Channel", **both** of which (at least for me and apparently other people) take you to a playlist view 
`https://www.youtube.com/channel/[YOUR_ACCOUNT_HASH]?view_as=subscriber`
which **only shows the text "Created playlists" with no dropdown to reach "Saved playlists"**.

Delete the "?view_as=subscriber" in your address bar and hit Enter to go to `https://www.youtube.com/channel/[YOUR_ACCOUNT_HASH]`
which should have links to

- Created playlists
- Uploads
- Liked videos
- **Saved playlists**
- Subscriptions

(Instead of that hash URL, the url `https://www.youtube.com/user/[YOUR_USERID]` with your user ID (see note at bottom) and no brackets also works, or you can even use just use https://www.youtube.com/user which will redirect you to the hash URL.)

Clicking on "Saved playlists" takes me to `https://www.youtube.com/user/[MY_USERID]/playlists?shelf_id=0&view=52&sort=dd` which shows just playlists by others that I have saved. I don't know if that "?shelf_id=0&view=52&sort=dd" string is universal.

---

You can also go to a "PLAYLISTS>All playlists" page that shows both playlists you've created and those created by others that you've saved, at the URL

`https://www.youtube.com/channel/[YOUR_ACCOUNT_HASH]/playlists`

This can be reached by clicking on the top-left hamburger ("☰") menu button, and then clicking on the word "LIBRARY" (which is easily mistaken for just an unlinked heading). Once again, there's an alternative URL to the hash one, which is  `https://www.youtube.com/user/[YOUR_USERID]/playlists` .

---

Frankly, the confusion is understandable. I don't see where the `https://www.youtube.com/channel/[YOUR_ACCOUNT_HASH]` / `https://www.youtube.com/user/[YOUR_USERID]` / https://www.youtube.com/user/ page is linked from anywhere in the UI, and as far as I can tell, the "PLAYLISTS>All playlists" page is currently linked from nowhere other than the word "LIBRARY" in the top-left menu, which looks like it's just a heading for the menu items "History", "Watch Later", "Favorites", etc. Unfortunately, YouTube's top-left and top-right menus are confusingly organized, poorly labeled, and partially redundant.

---

Note: The YouTube user ID being referred to is a no-space string. This is not the same as the (usually multiword) display name many people have. I don't know if all people have such an ID string. Quite possibly not, because hovering over peoples' names in YouTube reply threads, I see some names are linked to `https://www.youtube.com/user/[USER_ID]` while others are linked to `https://www.youtube.com/channel/[SOME_RANDOM-LOOKING_HASH]`.

Comment: This was NOT the issue, of course I had checked that there was no "?view_as=subscriber" in URL. (ps. I checked today and it seems that after years this bug has finally been fixed.)

Comment: @MarkusLaire Raquel described "by clicking on 'My Channel' first and then on 'Playlists', I finally got a screen with the same layout as yours". You said those steps resulted in plain text (making no mention of deleting anything from URL). *To this day, those steps result for me in plain text.*   If person A says "do X" and person B says "That results in Y", it's fair for person C to assume (after doing X and likewise seeing Y) that there were no additional steps.

Comment: @MarkusLaire  Perhaps Raquel's steps didn't result in that URL at the time, and the fact that those exact steps still result in the exact same behavior is some strange coincidence. If so, perhaps this answer will at least help someone else who experiences the exact thing described by you, because, as I said, it still happens.

Comment: Those steps have never resulted in URL containing "?view_as=subscriber" so there is nothing to delete from URL.

Comment: Are you saying "Those steps have never resulted in URL containing '?view_as=subscriber'" for *anyone*? Do you need a video? Here: https://i.imgur.com/udJn8LW.gif Again, I qualified it as "for **me**". Even if your photographic memory of *not* seeing a string a year and half ago is accurate, the URL does demonstrably appear now, accompanying the same exact UI behavior described, and therefore 1. it was a reasonable guess for what was affecting Kalec (the original asker, and presumably the one who upvoted before you downvoted) and you, and 2. my answer may yet help someone.